# Triggering a download from canvas.toDataURL client-side?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, download

I have a canvas element on a page. I call canvas.toDataURL() and now have a handle on its image data.

Do I need to post this data to the server, have my server construct a file stream using that data, then set my document's location to the file stream returned? Seems like a lot of overhead when I have all my data client-side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, check out [Canvas2Image.js](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)

```
// returns an <img> element containing the converted PNG image  
var oImgPNG = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas, true);     

// returns an <img> element containing the converted JPEG image (Only supported by Firefox)  
var oImgJPEG = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas, true);   

// returns an <img> element containing the converted BMP image  
var oImgBMP = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas, true);
```

Internally all it's doing is base64 encoding the data and calling `document.location.href = base64EncodedData;`.

Comment: How to set the file name?

Comment: My answer is pretty old-school even though it's less than a year old. Check this example out: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

Answer (score 0):

you could set the DataURL to a img elem

```
var plane = document.getElementsByTagName ( "canvas" )[0],
ctx = plane.getContext("2d"),   
img = document.createElement("img");
ctx.fillRect ( 0,0,400,400 );
img.src = plane.toDataURL();
document.body.appendChild ( img );
```

of course old ie don't support this